# twist model in wpf

Tags: wpf, transformation, bezier

In WPF program I want to twist the model(a cube). before, I used animation to do it,but failed, In this method I transform the point3D on asixY direction, but it make the model's triangle discrete. Is there some useful way to make the model twist like bezier curve.

Comment: i do it with animations, works very well. where was your problem?

Comment: i used animations,but i want make it twist like bezier